# Opening a txt file using argv and argc

Tags: c++

I have a code like below.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc != 2) {
    cerr << "Exactly one argument expected, got " << argc << "\n";
    return 1;
}



ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
if (!inFile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "error: failed to open '" << argv[1] << "'\n";
    return 1;
}
```

The code is complete but it does not work when I run on Debugger. I think it is because the code has no access to the actual text file. How do I let the code or program have access to the txt file?

Comment: Where is the text file? What are you passing as `argv`?

Comment: Text file is in the same directory as the cpp. I am writing a code that calculates distances between point 1 (x1,y1,z1) and other points(from 2nd up to more than 100) and the minimum distance between point 1 and point n, nth point that results in minimum distance. Argv is elements and argc is number of elements right? I got help from others and now have a complete code but don't know how to make code have access to the txt file

Comment: Don't just think that "the code has no access to the actual text file". *Know* it. Try specifying the full path to the file. Place the file at the same directory as your program. Have your program create a file and then read it.

Comment: Ask the system for the reason it didn't open the file.  Inspect `errno`.  Check `strerror(errno)` . Use `perror`.

Comment: You can provide the name of the file on commandline. How do you do that would depend on your environment. Are you using any IDE. WHich debugger you are using?

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure that you have given the filename with the extension. (e.g. input_file.txt)
- As far as I remember input file should be in the same file with the executable if you use a relative path.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know where to edit the command line argument